# difference between munch and many (satisfy p)?

Tags: parsing, haskell

In the module `Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP`, [`munch`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html#v:munch) (and `munch1`) documentation says:

> Parses the first zero or more characters satisfying the predicate. Always succeds, exactly once having consumed all the characters Hence NOT the same as `(many (satisfy p))`.

How are they different?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, let's find a counter-example and let's use Haskell tools to do it automatically. The [QuickCheck](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.7.6) library can give us such an counter-example very quickly:

```
import Data.Function (on)
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP
import Test.QuickCheck

prop_ParseTest :: String -> Property
prop_ParseTest input = on (===) runParser (munch pred) (many (satisfy pred))
  where
    runParser :: ReadP a -> [(a, String)]
    runParser = flip readP_to_S input -- run a given parser on a given input
    pred :: Char -> Bool
    pred = (> 'A')

main :: IO ()
main = quickCheck prop_ParseTest
```

We ask it to test, whether the two parsers `much pred` and `many (satisfy pred)` are the same. QuickCheck immediately finds that they're different and tries to produce as short counter-example as possible:

```
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 5 tests and 2 shrinks):    
[("a","")] /= [("","a"),("a","")]
```

So `munch pred` always consumes `'a'` unconditionally, while `many (satisfy pred)` gives a nondeterministic answer - it might or might not not consume `'a'`.

For example, consider running the following two parsers on string `"abcd"`:

```
test1 = munch (> 'A') >> string "cd"

test2 = many (satisfy (> 'A')) >> string "cd"
```

The first fails, because `munch` consumes the whole string and then it's not possible to match `"cd"`. The second one succeeds, because `many (satisfy ...)` creates all possible branches

```
[("","abcd"),("a","bcd"),("ab","cd"),("abc","d"),("abcd","")]
```

and `string "cd"` succeeds on the branch that consumed `"ab"`.

Comment: Besides showing an example where they are different, you also demonstrated how to find such an example using Haskell tools. Great answer!